# Applying clustering on any image

Tags: clustering

I want to clustering algorithm to the below image in jupyter platform. I'm trying to learn on my own. I do know how to implement the code but I don't know how to take the below image as an input dataset.

[image]

Comment: Why are you operating on the image, instead of the data points directly? If this is really about ingesting the image, it’s a programming question and off-topic for Cross Validated.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy this was definetly to the topic. It was just I was just wondering that.... But thankyou for taking time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking an image of dots as input and obtaining a list of coordinates of those points, this is nontrivial. You are far better off just creating your own set of points. Helpful libraries exist, e.g. [sklearn.datasets.make_blobs()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html#sklearn.datasets.make_blobs).

Comment: Actually, i found this image on somebook, so I thought can't I just applying clustering algorithm to this image directly.

Comment: but from your explanation, it is clear that it is not possible to do so (only possible by using data points). However, it seems make_blobs will suffice for this purpose. True?